# php: creating variables from array

Tags: php

I have a multi-part array that I want to grab a piece of and create a variable for it.  Below is a sample of the array:

```
array(17) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { 
      [0]=> int(1325003844) [1]=> array(2) { 
          [0]=> int(31) [1]=> string(19) "ONBOARD TEMPERATURE" } 
      }
```

There are 32 different parts like this where the value I want (like the text in quotes above) can be found at $foo[x][1] with x being a value from 0-31.  So I am wondering if I can use foreach or for to create a loop that will go through each iteration of the variable and pull that text and add it to a variable.

So the current code I have is:

```
if(isset($result[1][10])) { // If index 10 of $result exists
    $json_a =  $result[1][10];
    var_dump ($json_a);
```

To get the value I want in a single variable, I need to assing $foo_01 to $json_a[0][1] right now, and then do that 32 times.  ($json_a[1][1], $json_a[2][1], $json_a[3][1], etc.) I would rather just have one statement taht assigns them all at once.

Let me know if you need additional information. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you want to accumulate all the text into a single variable, or create a new variable for each instance extracted from the array?

Comment: I want to create a variable for each instance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can.

```
//Initialize an array variable to hold the names
$names= array();

//Creates an array of 32 strings (the names)
foreach ($items as $item){
    $names[]=$item[1]; 
}
//If you want to display all of the name at once, you can easily
//Implode the array to echo all of the items with a linebreak in between
echo implode('<br />', $names); 

//or you can cycle through the results and do something for each name
//although this can be done in the original loop.
foreach ($names as $name){
    echo $name.'<br />';
}
```

On a side note, the array architecture you show seems a little weird to me. Knowing not much at all about what you're trying to do, do you think a format like this would be better?

```
array(31) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        [id]=> int(1325003844),
        [name]=> "ONBOARD TEMPERATURE"
    }, 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        [id]=> int(1325003845), 
        [name]=> "NAME 2"
    }, 
    etc...
}
```

This way you already have your finished array, ready to loop through?

**UPDATE**

```
foreach($results as $result){
    if(isset($result[1][10])) { // If index 10 of $result exists
        $foo[] =  $result[1][10];
    }
}

//Then you can access each one when needed
echo $foo[1];
```

Comment: I tried working with these and I was not able to get it to work.I udpated my question to see fi I could make it a little clearer...

Comment: You wont be able to assign 32 different variables with a single statement. That's why arrays exist. Instead of `$foo_01` thru `$foo_32` you would use `$foo[0]` thru `$foo[31]` See Update

Comment: Thank you so much!  The array structure is unfortunately what I am fed from a JSON object.  But your comment actually showed me that I already can do what I want to do.  I have been adding the step of creating a variable to print the data I want, but I can just use $foo[1][10][0][1] as the actual variable. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you use two consecutive '$', PHP will actually use the value of a variable to create a new variable of that name. Example:

```
$var1 = 'variable2'
$$var1 = 'hello';

echo $var1;
echo $variable2;
```

Will output:

```
variable2
hello
```

From your above examples, though, your naming conventions dont seem to support that (there's a space in "ONBOARD TEMPERATURE") so, you might be better using an array with associative id keys. Example:

```
$values[$foo[x][1]] = $foo[x][0];
```

Would get you a variable of `$values['ONBOARD TEMPERATURE']` that would output `31`.